# Keeping Google User signed in on Website after refreshing

Tags: reactjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

Hi I am creating a website on react that uses Google Sign in API, one problem I encountered is that the user has to sign in again after refreshing the page or routing to the other pages. I wonder if there is a simple way for dummy like me to implement this. I'd really appreciate it.

```
import GoogleLogin from "react-google-login";

class About extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      url: "",
    };
  }
  responseGoogle = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.profileObj);
    this.setState({ name: response.profileObj.name });
    this.setState({ email: response.profileObj.email });
    this.setState({ url: response.profileObj.url });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleLogin
          clientId="35729443666-teiio5n42sr91viqbipavts334jc4u3i.apps.googleusercontent.com"
          buttonText="Login"
          onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
          onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
          cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
        />
        <h3>{this.state.name}</h3>
        <h3>{this.state.email}</h3>
        <img src={this.state.url} alt={this.state.name} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

Comment: the success callback returns a token. You should look at caching the token and using the existence of that token in your cache when the app starts up